# Registering a Struct for use with Qt Queued Connections

Tags: c++, qt

I have an object in a worker thread that needs to pass data back to its controller in the main thread.
There's several fields to move, so I'd prefer to do this using a struct.  The Qt docs make it clear that to use a custom type with Queued Connections, I need to use both Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and qRegisterMetaType.

The struct is declared in my worker class, which is inside a namespace.  In the header, after the class declaration, outside the namespace, I've included `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(myNamespace::myWorkerClass::myStruct)`.  I'm not sure where qRegisterMetaType belongs, so for the moment I've put it in the controller's constructor - `qRegisterMetaType(myWorkerClass::myStruct)`.

(I've tried several other configurations as well, but they haven't helped).
In each case, the program compiles happily but fails to execute the slot from the signal, outputting `QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'myStruct'`.

So it looks like there's something I'm not understanding.  Any clues?

Comment: Did you try with template and name argument to qRegisterMetaType? This is how I do it, basically called in main(): https://github.com/phys2/belki/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L29-L33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documentation states:

> To use the type T in queued signal and slot connections,
> qRegisterMetaType() must be called before the first connection is
> established.

So if you put the register in constructor, you have to instance your class once and then make the connection.

A common way to register the type is in main or with a static function register.

**Solution 1:**

**somewhere.h**

```
void registryCustonType()
{
   qRegisterMetaType(myWorkerClass::myStruct);
   // other registry for custom classes.
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
   registryCustomTypes();

    // ...
}
```

**Solution 2:**

**mystruct.cpp**

```
namespace {
   static const bool reg = qRegisterMetaType(myWorkerClass::myStruct);
}
```

I usually use the latter, which allow me to not specify any register function explicitely.